# Set Preferences not working and returning a null value when i use a Get Preference in other page (Shared Preferences)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to save my preferences for further use. So i make my onTap to call pilihKursi method, pilihkursi method is like this:

```dart
pilihKursi(){
    savePref();
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/pilihkursi');
  }

  savePref() async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      preferences.setString('namaPJ', widget.pj[widget.i]['namaPJ']);
      preferences.setString('namaArmada', widget.pj[widget.i]['namaArmada']);
    });
  }
```

But, when i use get preference in another page(/pilihkursi), and show it using Text widget, it's returning a null value(for namaPJ and namaArmada)

```
  String namaPJ, namaArmada;
  getPref()async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      namaPJ = preferences.getString('namaPj');
      namaArmada = preferences.getString('namaArmada');
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getPref();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child:
                  Icon(Icons.keyboard_backspace, color: Colors.white, size: 21),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Text("$namaPJ",//this variable show a null text in my app
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 5),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
              child: Text("$namaArmada",//this variable show a null text in my app
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Idk why the `savePref()` didnt working, because i have another similar page which is use a shared preference like Login Page is working fine

**--UPDATE--**

i'm sorry, it's just a wrong spelling. As you can see the key between set pref and get pref for `namaPJ` is different. And some mistake when using `setInt` for a `String` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Finally problem is in key in shared prefs it diffs `setString('namaPJ'` `getString('namaPj')`

I'd reviewed your snippet. Resolution - it should work

The one possible reason is that data you trying to set in prefs is `null`

```
widget.pj[widget.i]['namaPJ']
widget.pj[widget.i]['namaArmada']
```

Definetly check it for `null`

For your info - if there need to push some data to next screen you can pass it as arguments [readmore in docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

```
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
      '/pilihkursi',
      arguments: { // some Object or Map 
        'namaPj' : widget.pj[widget.i]['namaPJ'],
        'namaArmada': widget.pj[widget.i]['namaArmada'],
      },
    );
```

PS Feel free to reach me in comments

Comment: I already try to print the data before i make the set preference, and it's not null. And actually there is not just two data that i want to save for further use, if i just use an argument, i should write it every time i switch to other page, and that's not what i want

Comment: try fix shared prefs keys is equal when setString and getString